# BitmapImage.UriSource locks the local file

Tags: c#, uwp

In my UWP app when the Model layer tries to update (overwrite) the file, 
it throws the `UnauthorizedAccessException` 'Access is denied' exception because the file is locked by the View’s *BitmapImage*.

**View**

```
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/image.jpg");
```

**Model**

```
private async UpdateImage()
{
   // this line throws!
   var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("image.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
   ...
}
```

How can I stop *BitmapImage* from locking the local file used as its *UriSource*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it throws the UnauthorizedAccessException 'Access is denied' exception because the file is locked by the View’s BitmapImage.

As you known, if use [`BitmapImage.UriSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.urisource.aspx) property to set source for `BitmapImage` the file stream of the file will be lock busy. To solve this, we can read the file stream by our self by [`IRandomAccessStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241731) and in this case we can control when to dispose the file stream to unlock the file. Code updated as follows:

```
private async void btncreate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("image.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
}

private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    //bitmap.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/image.jpg");
    //imgshow.Source = bitmap;
    StorageFile imagefile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/image.jpg"));
    using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await imagefile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        bitmap.SetSource(stream);
        imgshow.Source = bitmap;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.BeginInit();
bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bitmap.CreateOption = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
bitmap.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/image.jpg");      
bitmap.EndInit();
```

Comment: `bitmap.CacheOption` would do that, but it is not supported by UWP as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the `CacheOption` property is missing in UWP.

Comment: Sorry, you are right I haven't noticed it was UWP.. I think you should manage the "reset" of the BitMapImage object of your View before call Model UpdateImage, and then reload in the View the updated image..

Answer (score 0):

The work around of "Sunteen Wu - MSFT" is almost correct, since bitmap.SetSource is implicit async, the stream may get disposed before SetSource is finished. You need to use the explicit function SetSourceAsync and await it.

Anyway, this solution uses a lot of memory. The URI-solution is somehow memory friendly (would love to know why).

The URI-solution will lock the file for an undeterminable long time. Eventhough the other solution locks no files, it will allocate a lot of memory for an unreasonable time.

I can share my solution:
I copy the original file to the temp folder, and then open it with the corresponding Uri. But then the file will not get deleted by me, which may cunsume a lot of disk space.

Does anyone have similar problems? Other solutions?